# Aligning images and forms horizontally using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: alignment fail]

I'd like to align these so that the login and signup are vertically aligned with the center of the braces, and that everything (except the input boxes/labels) is horizontal across the screen.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <body>
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}logo.png" class='center'></br>
<div style:"display:inline;">
    <a href='#' title='click to login' onClick='login()'>login</a>
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}leftParens.png" style:"display:inline">
    <form method='post' action='login' id='loginForm'>
    {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username">username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" face="helvetica"/>
        </br>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" face="AmericanTypewriter"/>
    </form>
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}rightParens.png" style:"display:inline">
    <a title='signup for omnicloud' href='signup' class='login_signup_button'>signup</a>
</div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
    src:url('AmericanTypewriter.TTF');
}

body{
    background-color:rgb(71,103,255);
    text-align:center;
}

img.center{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:500px;
}

    /* Used for braces */
form,fieldset,h1,h2,a,label{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font:30px/32px normal 'AmericanTypewriter', courier, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline;
}

a{
    vertical-align: 50%;
}

input{
     margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font:20px/22px normal 'AmericanTypewriter', courier, sans-serif;
   color:rgb(48,94,255);
}

    /* Used for login, signup, username, password */
#loginForm{
   display:block;
   margin:50px auto;
   height:100px;
}
```

The goal:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would rework your HTML to be arranged into boxes. For instance, I would put your `<a href>` for the login link and the corresponding `<img>` into a separate div; and do the same for the signup `<a href>` and `<img>`. Putting these tags into their own boxes would then allow you to absolutely position the login link, and move the login link to where you want it, **inside** the confines of the containing div. Not sure how you want the rest of your page positioned, can you clarify?

Comment: Oh that's a great idea! I've put a screenshot into the question to show you a mockup for what I'm going for

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. So, after you have created your signup and login divs, I would put those divs in a `<div id="content">` along with your `<form>`, and once again use absolute positioning to maneuver your parentheses divs into position within #content. Does that help?